# Alternate for SP.UI.ModalDialog in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007

Is there any alternate for SP.UI.ModalDialog in SharePoint 2007 ? how can we use Modal Dialog in SharePoint 2007 ?

Answer (score 2):

`commonShowModalDialog` is a little bit similar to SP.UI.ModalDialog but opens window in popup window. SPFieldUser and BDC field use this function to open their search pages. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215177/popup-in-sharepoint-2007) already answered how you can use this function

Comment: This is SharePoint 2007 functionality

Comment: sorry ill take that back it is ;), my bad

Answer (score 0):

somthing on the lines of:

```
function Confirm() {
    //create an input form
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    //make varible hidden
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    //varible
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    //text you want to show
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete this?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    //add to page the value to use in code behind
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

that is within the aspx or js file.

aspx button:

create a button in aspx and create an event call onClientClick event and call the method above.

or

to call the above within .cs:

create the button in aspx or though code behind, create a click event (not client click event).

```
    private void DeletButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button delID = sender as Button;

        string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
        if (confirmValue == "Yes")
        {
            Request.Form["confirm_value"].Remove(0, Request.Form["confirm_value"].Length);

            //if yes clicked do what you want
        }
        //do nothing if no or make else to do somthin when user clicks no
    }
```

now to register the client side (js) on the button call the method:

```
.OnClientClick = "Confirm();";
```

so through code:

```
                Button DeletButton = new Button();
                DeletButton.ID = " Delete";
                DeletButton.Text = "Delete";
                DeletButton.OnClientClick = "Confirm();";
                DeletButton.Click += new EventHandler(DeletButton_Click);
                this.Controls.Add(DeletButton);
```

or in aspx:

```
    <asp:Button ID="DeletButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" onclick="DeletButton_Click" OnClientClick = "Confirm();"/>
```